# 400 Request error on sending mail on hosted server

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, smtplib, flask-mail

I have a site developed in flask framework and it is hosted on a server. It has email sending feature
using smtp lib which will send mail to the registered user in a zip format . Problem that i'm facing is that it is working fine in the localhost system , but when i hosted this on server it is giving me 400 request code . I don't know how to slove this problem because it is working totally fine in the localhost system .

Here is code for sending the email:

```
def send_mail(recipient_mail,filename):
  with app.app_context():

    if(filename.endswith('.mp3') ) or filename.endswith('.wav'):

        temp_dir ="temp_files"
        if not os.path.exists(temp_dir):
            os.mkdir(temp_dir)
        audio_srt_path="/home/mechatt.tk/converted/SrtFiles/audio/" + filename[:-4]+".srt"
        audio_text_path="/home/mechatt.tk/converted/TxtFiles/" + filename[:-4]+".txt"
        file_paths = [audio_srt_path, audio_text_path]
        for file_path in file_paths:
            file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
            dest_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, file_name)
            shutil.copy(file_path, dest_path)
        zip_file_path = 'files.zip'
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w') as zip_file:
            for file_path in file_paths:
                file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
                zip_file.write(os.path.join(temp_dir, file_name))
        

        # Attach the zip file to the email message'
        message = MIMEMultipart()

        message['From'] = Constants.SENDER_EMAIL
        message['To'] = recipient_mail
        message['Subject'] = 'Zip file containing files'
        body = "Please find attached the zip file containing the requested files."
        message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        with open(zip_file_path, "rb") as zip_file:
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')
            part.set_payload(zip_file.read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(zip_file_path))
            message.attach(part)
        with smtplib.SMTP(Constants.SMTP_SERVER, Constants.SMTP_PORT) as server:
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.login(Constants.SENDER_EMAIL, Constants.SENDER_PASSWORD)
            
            server.sendmail(Constants.SENDER_EMAIL, recipient_mail, message.as_string())
            server.quit()
        
        os.remove(zip_file_path)
        shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
    elif filename.endswith(".mp4") or filename.endswith(".avi"):
        temp_dir ="temp_files"
        if not os.path.exists(temp_dir):
            os.mkdir(temp_dir)
        audio_srt_path="/home/mechatt.tk/converted/SrtFiles/video/" + filename[:-4]+".srt"
        audio_text_path="/home/mechatt.tk/converted/TxtFiles/" + filename[:-4]+".txt"
        file_paths = [audio_srt_path, audio_text_path]
        for file_path in file_paths:
            file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
            dest_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, file_name)
            shutil.copy(file_path, dest_path)
        zip_file_path = 'files.zip'
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w') as zip_file:
            for file_path in file_paths:
                file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
                zip_file.write(os.path.join(temp_dir, file_name))
        message = MIMEMultipart()

        message['From'] = Constants.SENDER_EMAIL
        message['To'] = recipient_mail
        message['Subject'] = 'Zip file containing files'
        body = "Please find attached the zip file containing the requested files."
        message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        with open(zip_file_path, "rb") as zip_file:
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')
            part.set_payload(zip_file.read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(zip_file_path))
            message.attach(part)
        with smtplib.SMTP(Constants.SMTP_SERVER, Constants.SMTP_PORT) as server:
            
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.login(Constants.SENDER_EMAIL, Constants.SENDER_PASSWORD)
            
            server.sendmail(Constants.SENDER_EMAIL, recipient_mail, message.as_string())
            server.quit()

        # Remove the temporary directory and the zip file
        os.remove(zip_file_path)
        shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
    

@app.route('/send-as-mail-background', methods=['POST'])
def send_as_email_background():
    global filename
    recipient_mail=session['Email']
    thread = 
threading.Thread(target=send_mail(recipient_mail,filename))
    thread.start()
    return redirect(url_for('home',sent=True))`
```

Here is SMTP config code:
class Constants:

```
SENDER_EMAIL="singharushi316@gmail.com"
SENDER_PASSWORD="******************"
SMTP_SERVER="smtp.gmail.com"
SMTP_PORT=587`
```

It is working fine in the localhost , but not  in the hosted server .
Any suggestion would be a great help for me . Thanks in advance

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you share the error message from the flask app?

Comment: "POST /send-as-mail-background HTTP/1.1" 400 - it's only error msg is coming on the server logs